# yii2 advanced template with docker/nginx/php8.2

Tags: docker, nginx, yii2, xdebug, php-8.2

I want to install Yii2 advanced template with nginx server , mysql 8 DB , php 8.2 , and to enable xdebug also inside

I tried to install template from official website [here](https://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/doc/guide/2.0/en/start-installation), & from git [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/tree/master), or [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-docker)

in **Dockerfile** :

```
FROM yiisoftware/yii2-php:8.1-apache

# Change document root for Apache
RUN sed -i -e 's|/app/web|/app/backend/web|g' /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

i tried to change it for :

```
FROM yiisoftware/yii2-php:8.2-fpm
```

but it seems there are other statements to be added ?

i tried those also :

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev \
    unzip \
    && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql zip

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the application code to the container
COPY . /app

# Change document root for nginx
RUN sed -i 's|/app/web|/app/frontend/web|g' /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

EXPOSE 80
```

but it dose not work , also i try to update **docker-compose.yml** to create separate nginx image but it's not working

*Related questions : *

- Where can i find php modules to add xdebug to it ?
- I tried to view `phpinfo()` file but it's not working also, i create it inside `/var/www/html`?
- For any change of configuration how can i restart server, or alternatively can i add them with docker build commands ?

Comment: Do you read the README.md file? `To enable Xdebug, set PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG=1 in .env file`

Comment: Test it with `docker-compose run --rm -e PHP_ENABLE_XDEBUG=1 php php -v`. You should get this string `Enabled xdebug`.